# Socket.IO and Node.js: Won't send data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on learning to use Socket.IO, and Node.JS, and I am trying to get started with making my own chat with it. however, the text is not showing up at all in the chat! can someone help me out here?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
   </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
   var socket = io();
   $('form').submit(function(){
     socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
     $('#m').val('');
     return false;
   });
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
     $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
   });
 </script>
 <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
       <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

Is it because of the version of socket.io or express that is causing that, or what is it? if you know why, thank you!

Comment: Have you added some `console.log` calls in your js and node server to see if chat messages are being sent and received? Are you able to view `/socket.io/socket.io.js` in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to move the script stuff to after the  tag. nvm then!

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue sometime back, it got receiving msges when i used broadcast.emit

```
 io.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
```